# Dynamic editor window is not correctly scaling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dynamic, screen-orientation

Afternoon,  Recently while trying to develop the more;  Err Graphical part of my 'Editor Extension',  Through towards unity3d's Audience I've been looking at creating more of a dynamic window for screen sizes!

Throughout my testing I've noticed many hard-core glitches that I cannot seem to persuade,  Currently I've tried "doubles,  int,  float,  etc.. etc..",  Though my issue might just be with unity,  I'm sure someone here has had this event occur while attempting to scale their "Editor Application",  Here are some visual representations of the variable issues i've been having.

[Error && Success Image Collection!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoWyy.jpg)

Upon my Journey of Dynamic Screen Fitting Here is some of my current attempted code that I have within my project for the window as of now.

```
private Rect Topic_Selection_Rect_Window = new Rect(5, 5, Screen.width / 6, 350);

static void Init()
{
    EditorWindow Toolbox = GetWindowWithRect(typeof(Toolbox), new Rect(0, 0, 1250, 900));
    Toolbox.Show();
}
private void OnGUI()
{
    BeginWindows();

    GUILayout.Window(0, Topic_Selection_Rect_Window, Topic, "Please Select A Listed Topic!");

    EndWindows();
}
private void Topic(int id)
{
    GUILayout.TextField("pre-text");
}
```

Now with the code shown above,  We Have on the "Price rect topic_selection_rect_window",  We have the idea that 'Oh,  we can just use the API for  'Screen.width',  Though initially i've noticed that the idea of that is knowing the users screen - information,  Though the reality of it is I'm thinking that initally it's all wonky for inital load to get user-information which I need to entail an idea on how to attempt to get that upon init,  Though i've tried hasn't seemed to work accordingly,  Though once I load and it's all wonky and I exit and load again it's less wonky and one last time and it's fine;  I've had some issues for some time such as "Screen.height" never seems to work and give me a good ## or Screen %% availability and just tends to not work with my monitor or what;  I'm fairly new to programming and I'm looking to figure out how this API works,  etc thanks for any

comments / answers!

-- DrEncompass --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After-Hours of tinkering,  I'd have given up while messing around I later had an issue with my window not being able to have de-bugging and I had to re-boot Unity3d Every-time I had crashed my Editor-Window,  So after some messing around I figured I could just directly call the window with the [.show();],  And so far it's appearing to be a strong solution!